# getTextContent from getElementsByTagName is null. how to handle?

Tags: list, xml-parsing, hashmap

I came up with this following situation right here, which i cannot handle. Can you please help me on this one?

Thanks

So i have an XML file like this which i need to parse and put values from tags into the hashmap. In that XML file i do not always have **name** tag.

```
<data>
 <entry>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Name1</name>
 </entry>
 <entry>
   <id>2</id>
 </entry>
 <entry>
   <id>3</id>
   <name>Name3</name>
 </entry>
</data>
```

And this is the code i use for parsing and putting the data into the hashmap

```
public Map idName = new HashMap();

...................
public Map parseResponse(int number) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    InputSource is;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response1));
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("id");
        NodeList list2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");

        for(int i = 0; i< number; i ++){
            id = String.valueOf(list.item(i).getTextContent());
            name = String.valueOf(list2.item(i).getTextContent());
            idName.put(id, name);
    }
    return idName;
  }
```

So the problem in this code is when it comes to the 2 which does not have a corresponding  tag, exception is being thrown and my program terminated.

how can i handle this case and let's say if there's no value for  tag i could put 'default' for the corresponding ?

Hope my point is clear. Please let me know if the description is not clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue myself.

So when it comes to the for loop i just do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i< number; i ++){
            if(null!=list.item(i)){
               id = String.valueOf(list.item(i).getTextContent());
            } else {
               id = "default id"
            }
            name(null!=list2.item(i)){
               name = String.valueOf(list2.item(i).getTextContent());
            } else {
               name = "default name"
            }
            idName.put(id, name);
```